# How to pipe help content to select-string in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I simply want to find specific part in the help about some command:

```sh
help rd | select-string -pattern 'cmd'
```

but I get nothing but errors. What is wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the ISE, the help function emits MamlCommandHelpInfo objects. Internally, the help function pipes the output of Get-Help to the 'more' utility (enables help paging in the console). In the ISE, 'more' is a simply writes to the pipeline whatever it gets.

To work around this, convert the output to strings. This will work in the ISE and in PowerShell console:

```
help rd | out-string -stream | select-string cmd
```

Comment: BTW: more in ISE is a very raw filter: filter more { $_ }

Answer (score 4):

```sh
help rd | Select-String -Pattern 'cmd'
```

Works for me. Alternatively, try this

```sh
help rd | ? {$_ -match 'cmd'}
```

Comment: but `help rd | select-string -pattern "cmd"` shows nothing. Isn't it supposed to print the text it found ?